# Successfully use time.conf (in PAM)

Tags: ssh, security, login, pam

I need to configure the `time.conf` (in PAM) to stop the user "`test`"
from having ssh access from 10 am to 1 pm. 
Aside from having this in the `time.conf` file
it seems I also need to activate this, but so far I have had no luck.

Currently I have this in my `time.conf` file:

```
sshd;*;test;Al1000-1300
```

I have also added the following line to the `/etc/pam.d/config-util`, `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/login` files:

```
account required pam_time.so
```

In the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I have `UsePAM yes`.

With all these settings,
I am still able to ssh into the server as `test` at any time of day. 
What do I need to do to get this working? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What can you see in the logs?

Comment: in the messages log when i ssh with the test user i get:  
Created slice user-1000.slice.  
Starting user-100.slice.  
started session 17 of user test.  
systemd-logind: New session 17 of user test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to have `!` before the time range, so the setting in `time.conf` is:

```
sshd;*;test;!Al1000-1300
```

Seems you need the `account required pam_time.so` line only in the file `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, and it needs to be the first of the `account` entries.